# Como fazer para que um método da interface receba qualquer objeto (tipo Object) como parâmetro?

Tags: java, interface, polimorfismo, objetos

Estou estudando polimorfismo agora, e não estou conseguindo compreender.

Dada a interface:

```
public interface View {
    public boolean existe(Object obj);
}
```

Eu tenho esse método, que gostaria de ser implementado da interface

```
public boolean existe(Diretor diretor) {
    for (Diretor d : this.tmDiretor.getLstDiretores()) {
        if (d.getId().equals(diretor.getId()))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Mas eu gostaria que o parâmetro da interface aceitasse *qualquer* objeto do tipo `Object`, como `Cliente`, `Diretor`, `Secretário`, etc., de acordo com a sua chamada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está usando o mecanismo errado. Neste casos não é para usar este tipo de polimorfismo. É para usar polimorfismo paramétrico. Algo assim:

```
public interface View<T extends Role> {
    public boolean existe(T obj);
}

public class AlgumaClasse implements Role<Diretor> {
    public boolean existe(Diretor diretor) {
        for (Diretor d : this.tmDiretor.getLstDiretores()) if (d.getId().equals(diretor.getId())) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Interface/Generic.java).

Note que `Diretor` e outros papéis que você quer usar desta forma devem herdar de `Role`. Poderia ser um outro tipo, mas precisa ter um tipo em comum. Pode ser `Object`? Pode porque ele é um tipo comum de todos objetos, mas quanto mais restrito essa hierarquia melhor. Pra falar a verdade do jeito que está a interface perde metade do sentido.

Mas pode ser que nem precise disto em algumas circunstâncias desde que o mesmo processamento seja aplicável para todos os objetos do tipo `Role`. Inclusive poderia ter a implementação na própria interface. Não vou postar aqui porque não sei se é possível para o seu caso.

Se tudo isto estiver confuso demais provavelmente precisa aprender alguns conceitos antes de passar para esse que é um pouco mais avançado.

E parece ter outros problemas, até conceituais neste código, mas não posso afirmar vendo tão pouco. Se tiver, tudo isto importa pouco porque fazer algo certo em cima de algo errado fica errado do mesmo jeito.